# Is it normal to have low mapping to bacterial genome in a total RNA sample of plant root-colonized bacterial cells?

Tags: rna-seq, deseq2, rna, read-mapping, bowtie2

I had isolated the total RNA from a sample of plant roots with colonized bacteria by excising the roots (harboring the bacterial cells) and crushing them into a powder using liquid nitrogen. The RNA isolation procedure was done following the kit's instructions specific for bacterial RNA.

The RNA was sequenced and the raw reads obtained were checked for mapping percentage with the bacterial genome's GTF file using bowtie2, as I need to study the expression of the bacterial genes. While the mapping was close to 80% for samples coming from the planktonic state, it was quite less - 0.4 to 0.56%, for all the samples coming from root colonized cells, obviously because a major part of it is comprised of plant RNA. Firstly, is this acceptable? Can I use these reads for further analysis?

Secondly, I use DESeq2 to analyze the data for upregulated and downregulated genes, comparing the colonized cells to the planktonic ones. Since the package includes a normalization step, is it safe to assume that although the mapping is less it does not influence the analysis significantly?